# How to handle a built in AlertController / Email Prompt from appearing behind my view

Tags: swift, modal-dialog, uialertcontroller

My app contains a modal UIView that can be presented from anywhere. How this works is the `present` method attaches the view as a subview on the key window:

```
func present(_ completion: ((Bool) -> ())? = { _ in }) {

    guard !isPresented else {
        return
    }

    if !isBackgroundReady {
        initializeBackground()
    }

    UIApplication.shared.keyWindow?.addSubview(backgroundView)
    UIApplication.shared.keyWindow?.addSubview(self)

    UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.3, animations: {
        self.backgroundView.alpha = 0.35
        self.alpha = 1.0
    }, completion: { _ in
        self.isPresented = true
        completion?(true)
    })
}

private func initializeBackground() {
    backgroundView.backgroundColor = UIColor.black
    backgroundView.alpha = 0.0
    backgroundView.frame = CGRect(x: UIScreen.main.bounds.midX, y: UIScreen.main.bounds.midY, width: UIScreen.main.bounds.width * 1.2, height: UIScreen.main.bounds.height * 1.2)
    backgroundView.center = CGPoint(x: UIScreen.main.bounds.midX, y: UIScreen.main.bounds.midY)
}
```

This modal contains an email link that users can click that opens up an email prompt (or an email action sheet if they long press it). This link is added by using the an `NSAttributedString` and it's `.link` attribute on a UITextView:

```
let supportString = NSMutableAttributedString(
    string: "general.supportEmail".localized(),
    attributes: [
        .link: "mailto:\("general.supportEmail".localized())",
    ]
)
supportTextView.attributedText = supportString
```

However, when the email prompt or action sheet appears, it is displayed behind the modal view:

[image: app]

Is it possible to get the prompt/action sheet to appear above the modal view with the current way I present the modal, or will I need to add some sort of recognizer somewhere that detects when one of these views appears and temporarily dismiss the modal until my app view comes back into focus? If it's the later, how would I accomplish that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The quick answer as to *why* this is happening is that you are presenting your custom modal view on top of the Window, which will be on top of everything, and your `UIAlertController` will be presented on the `UIViewController` presenting it (which is below your custom view).

One quick solution would be to always add your custom view as a subview on the current "top" `UIViewController`.  You can do that with a `UIViewController` extension - something like this:

```
extension UIViewController {

    static func topViewController(_ viewController: UIViewController? = nil) -> UIViewController? {
        let viewController = viewController ?? UIApplication.shared.keyWindow?.rootViewController
        if let navigationController = viewController as? UINavigationController, !navigationController.viewControllers.isEmpty {
            return self.topViewController(navigationController.viewControllers.last)
        } else if let tabBarController = viewController as? UITabBarController,
            let selectedController = tabBarController.selectedViewController
        {
            return self.topViewController(selectedController)
        } else if let presentedController = viewController?.presentedViewController {
            return self.topViewController(presentedController)
        }
        return viewController
    }

}
```

This extension will handle any `UIViewController` that is "on top", whether it's in a `UINavigationController`, a `UITabBarController`, or just presented modally, etc.  Should cover all cases.

After that you can adjust your `present` method to take this into account:

```
func present(_ completion: ((Bool) -> ())? = { _ in }) {
    guard !isPresented else {
        return
    }
    if !isBackgroundReady {
        initializeBackground()
    }
    guard let topViewController = UIViewController.topViewController() else { return }
    topViewController.view.addSubview(backgroundView)
    topViewController.view.addSubview(self)
    UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.3, animations: {
        self.backgroundView.alpha = 0.35
        self.alpha = 1.0
    }, completion: { _ in
        self.isPresented = true
        completion?(true)
    })
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of adding in the window, add the modal in the navicontroller -> topviewcontroller.

Link: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uinavigationcontroller/1621849-topviewcontroller.

This might help you.